# how does linux store negative number in text files?

Tags: linux, sorting

I made a file using `ed` and named it numeric. Its content is as follow:

```
-100
-10
0
99
11
-56
12
```

Then I executed this command on terminal:

```
sort numeric
```

And the result was:

```
0
-10
-100
11
12
-56
99
```

And of course this output was not at all expected!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort want to be asked to sort numerically (otherwise it will default to lexigraphic sorting)

```
$ sort -n numbers.dat
-100
-56
-10
0
11
12
99
```

Watch out for the "-n" parameter (see [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort))

Answer (score 4):

Text files are text files, they contain text. Your numbers are sorted alphabetically. If you want `sort` to sort based on numerical value, use `sort -n`.

Also, your sort result is strange, when I run the same test I get:

```
$ sort numeric
-10
-100
-56
0
11
12
99
```

Sorted alphabetically, as expected.

See https://glot.io/snippets/e555jjumx6

Answer (score 1):

Use `sort -n` to make `sort` do numerical sorting instead of alphabetical

Answer (score 0):

That's because by default, sort is alphabetical, not numeric. `sort -n` does numbers.

Otherwise you'll get

```
 1
 10
 2 
 3
```

etc.